# PutSql NIFI Processor Not working ? [Postgres Database]

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi

I have a NIFI flow and i want to update postgres database. But it is not working and not showing any error.

[NIFI Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvjHT.png)

[ReplaceText Processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3pKQ.png)

[PutSql Processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91UmM.png)

[Postgres Controller Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s5K3.png)

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: ok brother..But i have post these screenshots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SQL Statement property is for when you want to execute a statement (usually DDL) but want to retain the current flow file contents. According to your ReplaceText processor, you are trying to set the content to a SQL command. However, by specifying the SQL Statement property, PutSQL will try to execute that instead of the flow file content, and since it is set only to "UPDATE", that command won't work.

Instead, try leaving the SQL Statement property empty, and it will execute the SQL statement in the content of the flow file.